# Подключение графического интерфейса

Tags: c++, winforms, gui

Начал делать масштабный проект через консольное приложение, с мыслью «вот сейчас наберусь опыта в кодописании, а потом просто подключу интерфейс, и всё само заработает»... Ага, подключил..

Изначально я хотел использовать `WindowsForm`, т. к. там очень удобный конструктор, но я не подозревал, что он не работает с потоками из `std`, а использовать потоки через `System.Threading` вообще не вариант.
Думал об Qt, но адаптировать все стринги, мутексы, локгуарды и т.д. под Qt-шный стиль немного лень.
Есть ещё вариант с WinAPI, но он для меня абсолютно неудобен, и от многих фишек c интерфейсом придётся отказаться, а меня это не устроит.

Короче, сам вопрос: можно как-нибудь использовать интерфейс от `WindowsForm`, но что бы он не мешал моему `std`? Или какие ещё варианты есть?

Comment: CLI — это обобщённое понятие, «Command Line Interface» (интерфейс командной строки). Так что упоминание какого-то конструктора порождает вопрос о том, какую библиотеку вы для этого использовали. И откуда у вас `System.Threading`? Это тоже какой-то нестандартный класс из сторонней библиотеки (если говорить о C++).

Comment: Какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к C++?

Comment: @Arhad похоже, я запутался в понятиях. Я имел ввиду WindowsForm.

Comment: Пользовательский интерфейс можно выполнить в виде отдельного приложения-обёртки, которое будет запускать основную программу (имеющуюся на данный момент) в виде дочернего процесса без видимого консольного окна и транслировать пользовательские действия из GUI в текстовые команды для неё, а ответы транслировать обратно в GUI. Большим плюсом данного подхода является то, что вашу программу не придётся трогать вообще, а обёртка с GUI будет функционально изолирована от основной логики. Плюс, при желании вы сможете в будущем прикрутить таким же образом какие-нибудь другие интерфейсы.

Comment: @Arhad как вариант. Где об этом можно почитать? Я пока не представляю, как это реализовать.

Comment: Чтоб прям были отдельные руководства по этому — не знаю таких. Но можно поискать про запуск в WinForms или Boost программ как дочерних процессов без видимого окна и асинхронному обмену с ним данными через его стандартные потоки ввода вывода. Всё остальное — это рутина из разряда «пользователь сделал действие — либо сразу посылаем дочернему процессу то, что в при похожем случае вбивали бы руками, либо сначала спрашиваем у пользователя вспомогательные параметры. Программа прислала ответ — вносим соответствующие поправки в интерфейс, ...

Comment: ... может даже пользователю какое-нибудь сообщение или диалоговое окно при необходимости вывести»..

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите ncurses? wxWidgets? GTK?

Comment: @GarfieldCat, а это уже неважно. Тут полная свобода выбора, так как не придётся лезть в потроха исходной программы и что-то переписывать из-за выбора той или иной библиотеки GUI.

Comment: @Arhad так, погоди. Буст работает в WinForm? Если да, то не проблема все потоки переделать под буст. Только в таком случае не понятно, почему на std ругается, если он построен на основе буста

Comment: Boost — это вообще отдельная библиотека. Но если вы используете Winforms, то используйте его по максимуму, по возможности без других библиотек. Просто у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы ещё не определились с выбором, потому и накинул вариантов.

Comment: Если вы будете использовать Qt для графики, то переписывать типы под кьютишные совсем необязательно

Comment: @МишаковМаксим я уже пытался такое провернуть, но Qt ругается на все мои thread. Нужно где-то что-то прописать, что бы не ругался?

Comment: Нужно компилировать с ключом для C++11. Поищите в настройках вашей IDE.

Comment: @Vermww можно посмотреть на строку, на которую ругается Qt? Если у вас нет конфликта имён, то это интересно

Comment: @МишаковМаксим у меня сейчас всего пару ошибок выдаёт (644). в основном ругается на код в файле `mutex`, и немого на `chrono` и `memory`

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону TCL/TK